# How to use Poco::Net::MediaType

Tags: poco, poco-libraries

I need to be able to create a multipart mail message including images.

I found this suggestion [Sending HTML code in a mail using Poco library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438474/sending-html-code-in-a-mail-using-poco-library) but when I try this with VS2015/Windows/C++

Poco::Net::MediaType mediaType("multipart", "related");

I get

Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'int' AdvancedEmailer

Error   C2079   'mediaType' uses undefined class 'Poco::Net::MediaType' AdvancedEmailer

I've looked at https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.MailMessage.html but I can't figure out what's wrong

whats the correct usage for Poco::Net::MediaType

Comment: you, probably, forgot add include for `Poco/Net/MediaType.h`

Comment: So simple, thought I had it in MailMessage.h. Thanks